# PrimeNg Table method "dt.filter" doesn't filter character: "/"

Tags: primeng-datatable, primeng-table

I have an input in the column header to filter data in my primeng table

```html
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target['value'], col.field, 'contains')" placeholder="Filtrar"/>
```

The column shows dates

```
{{fecha | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}
```

It filters the numbers Ok

[image: image description]

But when I enter "/" it doesnt work.

[image: image description]

Is there any way to resolve that?

Thank you!